# How to column-align conditions inn if and guard statements in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, indentation

Google Swift Style Guide suggest if we use chained `if let` or `guard let`, then every `let` should have the same indentation.
If I use **CMD + I** in Xcode to indent the lets are not aligned.
How to change the Xcode config to column-aligns conditions in guard and if statements? How to add such rule to `Swift-Lint`?

**Default alignment in Xcode:**

```
if let value = aValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing(),
    let value2 = aDifferentValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing() {
  doSomething()
}

guard let value = aValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing(),
    let value2 = aDifferentValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing() else {
  doSomething()
}
```

**Desired alignment:**

```
if let value = aValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing(),
   let value2 = aDifferentValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing() {
  doSomething()
}

guard let value = aValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing(),
      let value2 = aDifferentValueReturnedByAVeryLongOptionalThing() else {
  doSomething()
}
```

[Source](https://google.github.io/swift/)
section : Control Flow Statements

Comment: This change is coming in Xcode 12.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa but the Google GuideLine refer to it 2 years ago, they must have  some approach to do it 
I tried Xcode Editor setting and swiftlint format with no luck to do it.